# Filtro de Range Mínimo e Máximo - JSON

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, rest, filter

boa noite.

Estou criando um projeto em Vue.JS 2x, onde renderizo em tela uma lista de usuários a partir de um JSON, estou consumindo esse JSON através de uma FAKE API REST, pelo pacote do JSON-SERVER.

Preciso criar um filtro que pega os valores Mínimo e Máximo da Longitude e Latitude, a partir desse filtro os usuários que estão dentro do filtro irá aparecer em tela.

Porém, não estou sabendo como fazer isso, não consigo criar uma lógica que funcione para isso.
Estou com muita dificuldade para executar esse filtro.

**Como posso resolver isso?**

Exemplo de RANGE para input ESPECIAL:

```
Longitude Mínima: -15.411580
Latitude Mínima -46.361899
Longitude Máxima: -2.196998
Latitude Máxima: -34.276938
```

**Filtro de Usuários**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Amostragem do JSON:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Template Vue com componente onde renderizo o data do JSON:**

```js
<template>
<div>
  <main>
    <div class="filter">
      <form>
        <p>Filtar por usuário:</p>
        <input type="radio" id="especial" name="filter" value="especial">
        <label for="especial">Especial</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="normal" name="filter" value="normal">
        <label for="normal">Normal</label><br>  
        <input type="radio" id="trabalhoso" name="filter" value="trabalhoso">
        <label for="trabalhoso">Trabalhoso</label><br><br>
      </form>
    </div>
   <div class="users">
     <div class="container">
       <li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" class="list-infos">
        <router-link :to="{name: 'UserPage', params: {id: user.email}}">
          <img :src="user.picture.large" alt="">
          <h1>{{user.name.first}} {{user.name.last}}</h1>
          <h3>{{user.location.street}}</h3>
          <p>{{user.location.city}}</p>
          <p>{{user.location.state}} - CEP: {{user.location.postcode}}</p>
        </router-link>
      </li>
     </div>
   </div>
  </main>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { api } from "@/services.js";

export default {
  name: 'UserList',
  data() {
    return {
      users: '',
      teste: '',
      userFilter: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      api.get(`/results`).then(r => {
        console.log(r.data);
        this.users = r.data;
      });
    },
    searchUser() {
      this.$router.push({ query: {q: this.teste} });
    },
  },
  computed: {
    url() {
      let queryString = ""
      for(let key in this.$route.query) {
        queryString += `&${key}=${this.$route.query[key]}`
      }
      console.log(queryString);

      return queryString;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getUsers();
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter {
  width: 30%;
  height: max-content;
  margin-right: 10px;

  form {
    background: #F4F4F4;
    padding: 30px 20px;

    p {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  }
}

.users {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  justify-content: center;

  .container {
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    width: 33.33%;
    width: 30%;
    background: #EDEDED;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;

    img {
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
  }
}


/* ================= Responsive ================= */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .header {
    flex-direction: column;

    .logo {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .search {

      form {
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;

        #search {
          max-width: 100%;
          width: 65%;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .filter {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }

  .users {
    .container {
      flex-direction: column;

      .list-infos {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que percebo você pode ter uma estrutura dos dados pequeno como também de tamanho gigantesco. Acho que o jeito mais adequado de fazer esse tipo de filtragem seria no back-end ao invés do front-end.

**Mas porque não da para filtrar no front-end?**

Enquanto você tiver uma estrutura de dados pequena fazer uso de uma **busca recursiva** seria uma ótima opção no front-end, mas pensando em um arquivos de dados de tamanho imensurável isso poderia carregar muito sua aplicação e causar sérios problemas de desempenho. Então trazer do back-end seria melhor opção.

Você poderia usar dos dados de latitude e longitude, restringi-los a tamanhos um pouco maior ou menor deles e com isso pedir para o back-end realizar a busca e lhe trazer dados ou no caso pessoas que estejam entre essas coordenadas.

Caso você opte por fazer a filtragem pelo front-end mesmo, lhe aconselho pesquisar sobre busca recursiva ou busca em árvore binária (para ter uma base), e aqui tem um link que fala um pouco mais sobre isso: [Árvore binária de busca](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca).

Espero ter ajudado. :)